# Popen command chaining returns 0 instead of 1

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, popen

So I'm kind of new in Python. I'm doing a log in form that redirects you to a python script running in a linux server to authenticate the user. I'm using multiple commands at once to see if the user is in the database. 
The command is echo "$password" | login -p -h 192.0.. $user >/dev/null 2>&1
and when I echo $? it supposed to return a 0 if it's in the database or a 1 if it's not.

In the python script I have this:

```
import cgi,shlex,subprocess

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

params={}

for key in form.keys():
   params[key]= form[key].value

user_name_variable=params['id']
password_variable=params['pwd']

command1="login -p -h 192.0. "+user_name_variable+" >/dev/null 2>&1"
command2="echo "+password_variable
command3="'echo $?'"
p1=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command2),shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command1),shell=True,stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p3=subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(command3),shell=True, stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
p2.stdout.close()
out, err= p3.communicate()[0]
```

and out comes up to be 0 always even if the input is wrong. Is there something wrong that I'm doing with the PIPE? What I know is that the problem is not when I'm passing the variables because I am getting the right variables. The problem must be in the chaining. I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$?` is a shell variable, it's not going to be meaningful here (each subprocess is run in its own subshell with `shell=True`; the `$?` from `login` is only visible in its shell, not the one you try to `echo $?` in).

But `Popen` objects already provide their exit status, so you don't need to run anything at all. You're also trying to use `shlex.split` to split commands with shell elements illegally (you either pass a single string and `shell=True`, or a sequence of arguments with `shell=False`; mixing them is illegal). You can shave off a lot of processes here too, and avoid running commands that would include the password in their command line:

```
# Define command as a list directly; making a string and splitting it is silly
command1 = ['login', '-p', '-h', '192.0.', user_name_variable]

# Only need a single Popen; we can pass it stdin and read its status directly
# As the shell command did, we throw away stdout and keep stderr
p1=subprocess.Popen(command1, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


# Sends the password, closes proc stdin, waits for proc to complete slurping
# the stderr (stdout was thrown away so it's returned empty)
_, err = p1.communicate(password_variable)

# Process is complete, so we can just ask for the return code
if p1.returncode != 0:
     ... handle failed run ...
```

Note: [`subprocess.DEVNULL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL) is new in 3.3; if you're on older Python, substitute:

```
with open('/dev/null', 'wb') as devnull:
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(command1, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=devnull, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

or just change it to `subprocess.PIPE` and ignore the captured stdout output.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that approach doesn't work in bash, either:

```sh
false | echo $?  # echoes 0
```

Skip `p3`, and instead of `p3.communicate`, run `p2.communicate`. After that, [simply check `p2.returncode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#subprocess.Popen.returncode).